# In R, dplyr mutate referencing column names by string

Tags: r, dplyr

```
mydf = data.frame(a = c(1,2,3,4), b = c(5,6,7,8), c = c(3,4,5,6))
var1 = 'a'
var2 = 'b'

mydf = mydf %>% mutate(newCol = var1 + var2)
```

in our code, `var1` and `var2` can refer to different columns in `mydf`, and we need to create `newCol` by taking the sum of values in the columns whose names are saved in `var1` and `var2`. I understand this can be done outside of `dplyr`, however I am wondering if there is a solution that uses dplyr and %>% like above.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can convert to `sym`bol and evaluate with `!!`

```
library(dplyr)
mydf %>% 
  mutate(newCol = !! rlang::sym(var1) + !! rlang::sym(var2))
```

Or another option is subset the column with `.data`

```
mydf %>%
   mutate(newCol = .data[[var1]] + .data[[var2]])
```

---

or may use `rowSums`

```
mydf %>% 
   mutate(newCol = rowSums(select(cur_data(), all_of(c(var1, var2)))))
```